# What does "planet in parole" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I encountered this sentence in [nature.com](http://www.nature.com/nature/podcast/v456/n7218/nature-2008-11-06.html)

> Obama cited a **planet in parole** among the leading challenges that his presidency is going to face.

What does "planet in parole" mean?

---

The context:

> Adam Rutherford: Okay, so you have mentioned climate change, what are the other big issues for scientists that the democrats will try and push through?
>
> Mark Peplow: Well, energy and environment is a huge issue and you know in his acceptance speech last night, Obama cited a **planet in parole** among the leading challenges that his presidency is going to face and he did promise a 150 billion dollar push in new energy research and that's something which is obviously going to have a massive impact on science and if that actually goes through as promised.

Answer (score 5):

The quoted text is likely a wrong transcription of what was said.

More likely, Obama said "planet in peril", which is a very common idiom meaning the planet (Earth) faces danger of some kind.

Comment: In Obama's first inaugural address, he used the phrase "planet in peril": http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2008/nov/05/uselections2008-barackobama

Comment: "For even as we celebrate tonight, we know the challenges that tomorrow will bring are the greatest of our lifetime – two wars, a planet in peril, the worst financial crisis in a century."